# Question about the declaration about the aliasing constructor for `std::shared_ptr`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I think the [8th constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) of the `std::shared_ptr<T>` should be decalared as

```
template< class T, class Y >
shared_ptr<T>( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

other than

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

Sorry for my poor English, [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/991PEzzjE) may make the question more clear to you:

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

struct Widget
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int var;
};

int main()
{
    auto wp{std::make_shared<Widget>(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}, 69)};

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vp{wp, &wp->vec};
}
```

You see, `vp` is `std::shared_ptr<vector<int>>`, whereas `wp` is `std::shared_ptr<Widget>`.
So, I think the declaration for the said constructor should be `template< class T, class Y >` other than `shared_ptr<Y>`.

**ADDED**:Why I want to make such modification for the said declaration? I just want to emphasise that the type of the aliasing constructor constructed(i.e. `shared_ptr<T>`) is different from the object which is passed as parameter. (i.e. the type of the argument is `shared_ptr<Y>`).

**NOTE**: As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), **the 8th constructor is avilable in `C++11`**, but it seems that the code sinppet above does not compile with `C++11`, so I have to set the compilation option to `C++20`. And the tag for this post is still `C++11`, not a clerical error. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: What would `T` mean in your proposed constructor, and how would it be deduced? If you meant the template parameter of `shared_ptr` itself, then all member functions already can access it automatically.

Comment: Your code requires C++20 because `Widget` is an aggregate (has no custom constructors, more or less), and `make_shared` tries to initialize it with parentheses. That only works in C++20, prior to that you had to use braces.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For `T`, I just want to emphasise that the **type** of the *aliasing constructor*  constructed is **different** from the  object which is passed as parameter. (i.e. the type of the argument is `shared_ptr<Y>`). You see, `vp` is `std::shared_ptr<vector<int>>`, whereas `wp` is `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` in the demo code snippet. I think there is something wrong. Could you please point out it?

Comment: But that was already achieved by adding `typename Y`? If the constructor required a `shared_ptr` parameter of the same type, it wouldn't be a template at all, and would look like `shared_ptr(const shared_ptr &r, element_type *ptr)`.

Comment: @fabian No the document says that the second overload taking an `rvalue` is available since `C++20`, whereas the one for `lvalue` is not. Please read the document again. *** template parameters of constructors are independent of the template parameters of the type they construct.*** Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the clarification. If I understand you correctly, there is **already** `typename T` for the class `std::shared_ptr<T>`, and `typename Y` make the aliasing constructor as a templated function. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

There has already `typename T` for the class `std::shared_ptr<T>`, and `typename Y` makes the aliasing constructor as a templated function:

```
namesapce std
{
    template <typename T>
    class shared_ptr
    {
         template<typename Y>
         shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
    } 
}
```